# Finding if a Valid Rummikub Solution exist from selected Tiles

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently making a rummikub "game" so that when I make a [Mistake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rummikub#Mistakes) I am able to get the board back easily to what it was before.

Currently in need to find out for a given number of tiles if a solution exists and what the solution is.

Example

Elements Selected are
{Red1, Red1, Blue1, Black1, Orange1, Orange1}

And a solution would be
{Red1, Blue1, Orange1} and {Red1, Black1, Orange1}

I can currently determine which groups and runs are possible ({Red1, Blue1, Black1, Orange1} being a valid group that wouldn't appear in the valid solution). I need a solution that can go the next step and tell me which of the groups/runs can exist together and make sure each tile is used once. If no such solution exist, it needs to be able to report that. The solution does not have to be optimal (ie use the smallest number of groups/run), it just has to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a method of determining what groups and runs are possible, why don't you modify your algorithm to remove tiles that you have already used, and make the function recursive.  Here is some pseudo-code:

```
array PickTiles(TileArray) {

    GroupsArray = all possible groups/runs;

    foreach Group in GroupsArray {
         newTileArray = TileArray;
         remove Group from newTileArray;

         if(newTileArray.length() == 0) {
               return array(Group);
         }

         result = PickTiles(newTileArray);
         if(result.length() > 0) {
               return result.append(array(Group));
         }
    }

    return array();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I was building all possible solutions as they selected tiles, not finding all solutions as a function which you feed tiles into. I'll have to move some code around, but this will work great. Is this algorithm based on a more common one, or is it something you've just come up with?

Comment: Mostly just something I came up with, although I play with puzzle solving algorithms occasionally as a diversion, usually word-based jumble-type puzzles.

Answer (score 3):

Finding the highest scoring solution for a given set of tiles is a tough problem. It has already been the subject of many papers. The most recent approach is ILP (integer linear programming).

Basically, it means you define a function you wish to maximize, and put constraints on it.
For instance:

- make a list of all unique tiles (53 in a standard game)
- make a list of all possible valid sets (1174)

Define:

- yi = number of times tile i is chosen in optimal solution
- sij = indicates wether tile i is in set j
- ti = number of times tile i can be found on table
- ri = number of times tile i can be found on rack

G = y1 + y2 + ... y52 + y53

Then it follows that:

- sum[ xj*sij, j=1...1174 ] = ti + yi (i=1...53)
- yi<=ri (i=1...53)
- 0 <= xj <= 2 (j=1...1174)
- 0 <= yi <= 2 (i=1...53)

The solution will be given by the coefficients of xj (telling you exactly what sets to include in your solution). The function to maximize is of course G.

This approach is able to solve a given situation rather fast (1 second for 20 tiles).

Comment: This is the approach first proposed by D. Den Hertog, P. B. Hulshof (2006), "Solving Rummikub Problems by Integer Linear Programming", *The Computer Journal, 49(6)*, 665-669 ([DOI 10.1093/comjnl/bxl033](https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/bxl033)). Note that they include sets with jokers in their valid sets that I would not want to play (e.g. a run of 9, 10, 11, joker, where the joker is redundant). In my implementation of the algorithm I exclude such sets, which make up more than 1/3rd of the sets generated otherwise!

Comment: And even with GLPK (which is not the fastest of MILP libraries out there), this takes in the order of 10 milliseconds to work out, not 1.2 seconds.